# Azure Blob Container With Access Level Set to Private Still Allows Anonymous Downloads

Tags: azure, security, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure blob container, that previously was set to public read access, and was used to allow the client to directly download files from an azure blob url anonymously.

For security reasons, I am required to prevent direct anonymous url downloads from this container. So I have set this container to private access to prevent this.

However I appear to still be able to download files from this container using the old urls. For instance in chrome, in incognito mode, without passing any sort of authentication or token.

The url is in this format: https://{ACCOUNT NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/{CONTAINER NAME}/{FILE NAME}

Am I misunderstanding private access?

Comment: Thank you, previously I think when the Web Developer is open, the cache is automatically get disabled, in my case, which is not true.This can be set in network view of Web Developer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like my browser had the file cached. After clearing my cache I wasn't able to access the file anymore.